# Dapper.Net: IEnumerable<long> parameter throws exception: No mapping exists from object type System.Int64[] to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, dapper, where-in, in-subquery

I am using Dapper.Net against SQL Server 2008 R2 in the following code to pass a `List<long>` parameter to run a SQL query that has a WHERE IN clause, but I get the exception:

**No mapping exists from object type System.Int64[] to a known managed provider native type.**

By the way, company_name_id and industry_id are bigint types.

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@companyNameId", entry.Id);
parameters.Add("@industryIds", deletedIndustryIds);
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["server1"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    connection.Execute("DELETE FROM company_name_industry_map WHERE company_name_id = @company_name_id and industry_id IN @industryIds", param: parameters);
    connection.Close();
}
```

I did see in the github [documentation](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) that Dapper has List support, but I was wondering `List<long>` is supported.

According to the older documentation on https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ it does seem like only **int[]** is supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the exception happens you use try to pass a list if the parameter object is of type **DynamicParameters**.

My workaround was create set param object as an **anonymous** object; the following code worked instead.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["server1"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    connection.Execute("DELETE FROM company_name_industry_map WHERE company_name_id = @company_name_id and industry_id IN @industryIds",
new { company_name_id = entry.Id, industryIds = deletedIndustryIds });
    connection.Close();
}
```